# ¿Cómo acceder a una variable booleana que está dentro del Componente en FlutterFlow?

Tags: flutter

Tengo un componente que tiene una variable booleana (presionado) que indica si está presionado o no. Este componente se repite como se muestra en la imagen unas 15 veces y necesito en un momento dado cambiar la variable de estado de todos ellos (refresh)

Y llevo mucho tiempo intentándolo y no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

Cuál es la solución ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]